# numpy multiply arrays with different shapes

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have an array `A` of shape `(w,h) = 3000,2000`
and another array `B` of shape `d = 100`

I want to multiply each value of `A` by `B`, and get the result in the form of an array `C` of shape `(w,h,d) = 3000,2000,100`

Right now I am using the very slow code below, how can I vectorize this operation?

```
w,h,d = 3000,2000,100

A = np.ones((w,h))

B = np.arange(d)

C = np.zeros((w,h,d))

for i in xrange(w):
    for j in xrange(h):
        C[i,j] = A[i,j] * B
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use numpy [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Try this

```
from numpy.random import rand
a = rand(4,5)
b = rand(6)
c = a[...,None] * b
print (c.shape)
```

Or equivelently

```
c = a.reshape(4,5,1)*b
```